# How to force override method and call super at the same time

Tags: java

Ok, so recently I wanted to implement the following

```
public enum ObjectTypes {
    STRING,
    INTEGER
}

interface IObjectEnhancer{
    void enhance(String s);
    void enhance(Integer i);
    ObjectTypes getLastEnhancedType();
}

class ObjectEnhancer implements IObjectEnhancer{
    ObjectTypes lastUsedType=null;

    @CallSuper
    @Override
    public void enhance(String s) {
        this.lastUsedType=ObjectTypes.STRING;
    }

    @CallSuper
    @Override
    public void enhance(Integer i) {
        this.lastUsedType=ObjectTypes.INTEGER;
    }

    @Override
    final public ObjectTypes getLastEnhancedType() {
        return lastUsedType;
    }
}

class ObjectEnhancerChild extends ObjectEnhancer{
    @Override
    public void enhance(String s) {
        super.enhance(s);
        //child code
    }

    @Override
    public void enhance(Integer i) {
        super.enhance(i);
        //child code
    }
}
```

And for safety I wanted to add `@CallSuper` because I really want only the parent to remember the types but I also want the `enhance(String)` and `enhance(Integer)` to be `abstract` so that no clumsy future person (me included) forgets to actually implement these methods.

So below is a method to handle this sort of situation that apparently only I am having and the internet doesn't really have advice on, it might seem stupid to worry about such a small thing but if you have 10+ methods it stars becoming a nightmare(feedback and other solutions welcome):

Comment: Enum constants should be in UPPER_SNAKE_CASE, according to the Java Naming Conventions.

Comment: @MCEmperor duly noted

Answer (score 1):

Just make new `abstract` methods so that the child is forced to implement them and parent methods call the `abstract` methods instead of using `@CallSuper`:

```
abstract class ObjectEnhancer implements IObjectEnhancer{ //add abstract to parent
    ObjectTypes lastUsedType=null;

    abstract void enhance2(String s); //new
    abstract void enhance2(Integer i); //new

    //removed @CallSuper
    @Override
    final public void enhance(String s) { //changed to final
        this.lastUsedType=ObjectTypes.String;
        enhance2(s); //new
    }

    //removed @CallSuper
    @Override
    final public void enhance(Integer i) { //changed to final
        this.lastUsedType=ObjectTypes.Integer;
        enhance2(i); //new
    }

    @Override
    final public ObjectTypes getLastEnhancedType() {
        return lastUsedType;
    }
}

class ObjectEnhancerChild extends ObjectEnhancer{
    @Override
    public void enhance2(String s) { //changed to abstract method
        //removed super.enhance(s);
        //code
    }

    @Override
    public void enhance2(Integer i) { //changed to abstract method
        //removed super.enhance(i);
        //code
    }
}
```

Comment: FWIW, this approach is called "Template Method" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern

Comment: @Thilo I really wish google pointed me to this page when trying to figure out a solution, thx. Tried searching for all kinds of abstract + Override +CallSuper combinations.